# How do sites like Google and Aol prevent the user from accessing the login form after logging in?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to implement a log-in (Django) form which, ideally, should not be visible to the user after he/she has signed in. The problem occurs when i press the back button of the browser. Since the button acts like a stack, it immediately plops the previous page without making any requests (if i can't receive a request, i don't think i'll be able to redirect the user to the desired page). Not sure how, but both Google and Aol are able to prevent this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last project I did with Django had the requirement that it explicitly shows the user that they were already logged in. So I did it in the frontend. It may serve for your purposes as well.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>You are already logged in.  <a href="{% url 'home' %}"> Go to the home page.</a></p>
{% else %}
<h2>Login</h2>
<div style="width:50%;">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
</div>
<p>Not yet a member? <a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}?next={{request.GET.next}}"> Sign Up</a>. Forgot your password?
    <a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Reset it here.</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: rather than using the user.is_authenticated method i am using the session key to see if the user is already logged in. Is there a way to access that in the HTML? If so, do tell?

Comment: the session key is working fine. the user is redirected to the details page whenever he/she tries to reenter their credentials. This prevents duplicate sign-ins. Now, in accordance with what you have stated, i just need to see if the session key exists to notify the user whether he/she has already logged in

Comment: @Moaz_ yes, you can access session with something like `{{ request.session.key}}` there is a context processor which you need to add as well. Let me go find that.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like the context processor for sessions ins now in the default setup.

Comment: yes it is. And you're right, it is now present in the default setup

Answer (score 2):

view :

```py
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
```

This redirect to home page if user is authenticated (logged in) or will stay at the page if he is no authenticated.

Comment: this .user in request.user.is_authenticated. is this the django user model

Comment: No, it is part of `request` parameter we defined.

Comment: could you kindly provide an example of how the user parameters are set, or where?

Comment: You need to get the logged in user info ? Please clarify more.

Comment: `request.user` can be an instance of your settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL (django.contrib.auth.models.User by default) if the user is logged in or it can be an `AnonymousUser` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object

Comment: now here is the problem. I am not using the auth_user_model. i created a separate model for it, a simpler one with an email address and a password

Comment: Did you create as the docs mention or you created it from scratch ?

Comment: i simply used the models.Model in the models.py file. I avoided the making the custom django user mode- a subset of the django User

Comment: So you haven't defined `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings?

Comment: and i don't think that this would work as the back button on the browser(safari) simply show the cached version of the page after i click it.

Comment: i did at one point use the auth.models import User, but i felt that the custom version was a little complex for me.

Comment: Please do not create a custom user model using `models.Model`, create it using `AbstractBaseUser`, check here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: as an example, try doing the following: Log in to stack overflow (i used the gmail account). Afterwards, press the back button on the browser (i am using safari). You'll be directed back towards the log-in form even after having signed in